# How to do a DB update of two separate yet associated arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using Laravel, however in this case, I think that is irrelevant.

I have 1 array, $materials pulled from a form using $materials = $request->except() which delivers 2 sub arrays, product_code and quantity. So $materials looks like this:

```
{

"product_code": 

[

"123",
"234",
"128"

],
"quantity": 

[
    "50",
    "50",
    "50"
]

}
```

Ok - I need to do an update of the DB table. The table has 2 columns, 'product_code' and 'quantity'

I was thinking I need a foreach loop to update each row:
product_code => Quantity

**Problem: How do I update my DB, when the array is not organised in a
$key =>value pair ?**

Secondly, is using a foreach() the best way to do it ? I have about 30 products.

Currently I have a foreach loop, which I can not see working for a DB update:

```
        foreach($materials as $key=>$value) {
            echo $key."<br>";

        foreach ($value as $k=>$v) {
           echo($v)."<br>";

        }
    }
```

And I get this out of it:

```
product_code
123
234
128
quantity
50
50
50
```

Many thanks !

Comment: You can do `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` and then use `$key` in the second array as long as the keys line up.

Comment: "when the array is not organised in a $key =>value pair" but you know how your table looks like right?

Comment: @daremachine Thanks ! sure, the table columns are next to each other.

Comment: i don't understand correctly. Pls can you explain what you expect? You have products and quantity and what you need to do with this and how? Which relations have between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = $request->get('product_code');
$qty = $request->get('quantity');
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    DB::table('product')->where('product_code', $id)->update(['quantity' => $qty[$key] ]);
}
```

Comment: This looks really great. I was not aware of the request->get() method. However, I am still not quite there. 

I need to update BOTH product and quantity.  And they are separate arrays. so, I am thinking perhaps using array_combine(). As you have Laravel knowledge, What do  you think, is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do a for loop like the following (if your data is not in json then just ignore the json decode:

```
<?php
$json = '{"product_code": ["123","234","128"],"quantity": ["50", "50", "50"]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['product_code']); $i++)
{
    echo "UPDATE stuff with the ID " . $data['product_code'][$i] . " and the quantity " . $data['quantity'][$i] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

This will print

[image]